# JQuery Mobile - my left menu goes down all the content of my page

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I use JQuery-Mobile for some components in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. But I have a display problem.

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function (d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=679266642148477&version=v2.0";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="userMenu" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="g">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
            <li id="menuTxt" data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/Home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/CheckFridge">Mes ingr&eacute;dients</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/AddRecipe">Ajouter une recette</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="#">D&eacute;connexion</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/MyRecipes">Mes recettes</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/">Partager</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="menuBtn" href="#userMenu"></a>
        <img id="icook_logo" src="~/Content/images/icook_logo.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="ui-content">
        <a data-role="button" href="@Url.Action("Index", "CheckFridge")" data-theme="c" data-ajax="false" id="checkFridgeBtn">Check mon frigo</a>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="c" id="classicSearch">Recherche classique</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Since that I've added a left menu(), all the content is at bottom of my page.

Top of my page :

[image]

Bottom of my page :

[image]

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your ui-content div. If you are using jQM version 1.4.x it should be:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
```

If you are using 1.3.x:

```
<div data-role="content">
```

Comment: Thank you. It works excepted that when I click on the left button on the top of the page, the rest of the page doesn't go to the right anymore

Comment: Here is your code in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/69q49/1/ It slides right just fine...

Comment: @user2274060, maybe you are applying some CSS you have not shown in the question?